# PHP LaravelMerge data to single array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel

I am trying to get data from DB into a single array

This what I have tried:

```
foreach ($userid as &$user){

        foreach ($first_week_of_month as $day){
        //Get Total Number of Personal Leads By User ID & Requested week Through Each Day
        $personalleads = \DB::table('leads') 
        ->where('owned_by_id', $id) // User ID
        ->where('lead_source_id', 7) // 7 = Personal Lead
        ->get(); // Get All Data
        $user->pleads = $personalleads->count();

        //Get Total Number of leads Created by Managers By User ID & Requested week Through Each Day
        $managerleads = \DB::table('leads') 
        ->where('owned_by_id', $id) // User ID
        ->where('lead_source_id', 3) // 3 = Manager Lead
        ->get(); // Get All Data
        $user->mleads = $managerleads->count();

         //Get Total Number of leads Created by Admins By User ID & Requested week Through Each Day
        $adminleads = \DB::table('leads') 
        ->where('owned_by_id', $id) // User ID
        ->where('lead_source_id', 4) // 4 = Admin Lead
        ->get(); // Get All Data
        $user->aleads = $adminleads->count();
        echo ($userid);
        }
    }
```

**What I want:**

```
[  
   {  "userid":1, "pleads":2, "mleads":1, "aleads":1   },
   {  "userid":1, "pleads":0, "mleads":0, "aleads":0   },
   {  "userid":1, "pleads":0, "mleads":0, "aleads":0   },
   {  "userid":1, "pleads":1, "mleads":0, "aleads":0   },
   {  "userid":1, "pleads":1, "mleads":0, "aleads":0   },
   {  "userid":1, "pleads":1, "mleads":0, "aleads":0   },
   {  "userid":1, "pleads":0, "mleads":0, "aleads":0   }
]
```

**What I get:**

```
[ {  "userid":1, "pleads":2, "mleads":1, "aleads":1   } ]
[ {  "userid":1, "pleads":0, "mleads":0, "aleads":0   } ]
[ {  "userid":1, "pleads":0, "mleads":0, "aleads":0   } ]
[ {  "userid":1, "pleads":1, "mleads":0, "aleads":0   } ]
[ {  "userid":1, "pleads":1, "mleads":0, "aleads":0   } ]
[ {  "userid":1, "pleads":1, "mleads":0, "aleads":0   } ]
[ {  "userid":1, "pleads":0, "mleads":0, "aleads":0   } ]
[]
```

`print_r` of **what I get:**

```
( [items:protected] => Array ([0]=> stdClass Object ([userid]=> 1[pleads]=> 2[mleads]=> 1[aleads]=> 1 )) ) 
( [items:protected] => Array ([0]=> stdClass Object ([userid]=> 1[pleads]=> 0[mleads]=> 0[aleads]=> 0 )) ) 
( [items:protected] => Array ([0]=> stdClass Object ([userid]=> 1[pleads]=> 0[mleads]=> 0[aleads]=> 0 )) ) 
( [items:protected] => Array ([0]=> stdClass Object ([userid]=> 1[pleads]=> 1[mleads]=> 0[aleads]=> 0 )) ) 
( [items:protected] => Array ([0]=> stdClass Object ([userid]=> 1[pleads]=> 1[mleads]=> 0[aleads]=> 0 )) ) 
( [items:protected] => Array ([0]=> stdClass Object ([userid]=> 1[pleads]=> 1[mleads]=> 0[aleads]=> 0 )) ) 
( [items:protected] => Array ([0]=> stdClass Object ([userid]=> 1[pleads]=> 0[mleads]=> 0[aleads]=> 0 )) )
```

Comment: i dont see a difference in your expected result

Comment: How what i get is multiple arrays [],[],[] what i want a single array [{data},{data},etc]

Comment: well apparently your `$userid` is something different than you are expecting

Answer (score 2):

Take `$result = []` before starting forloop and Just add this one line where you are `echo $userID`

```
array_push($result, $user);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but i got error Array to string conversion
can you post your answer with my code ? please

Comment: `$user` should be prepared array e.g `$user = ["userid":1,"pleads":2,"mleads":1,"aleads":1]` not string

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can try `array_merge( array $array1 [, array $... ] )`